# Testing a DocumentProvider with ProviderTestRule

Tags: android, android-testing, document-provider

I have a DocumentProvider backed by files on disk that I want to test with instrumented tests. I can not find a recommended way to do this unfortunately. In the docs there is `ProviderTestCase2` which seems like it's going to be deprecated along with [`IsolatedContext`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/IsolatedContext).

The new way of doing it seems to be `ProviderTestRule`, but I can not get it to work with any `DocumentProvider`.

My Manifest:

```
<application>

    <provider
        android:authorities="${documentsAuthority}"
        android:name="com.example.asd.MyProvider"
        android:exported="true"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true"
        android:permission="android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.content.action.DOCUMENTS_PROVIDER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </provider>
</application>
```

And my Instrumented test:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class ExampleInstrumentedTest {

    @get:Rule
    public val permission = GrantPermissionRule.grant(Manifest.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS)
    @get:Rule
    public val rule = ProviderTestRule.Builder(VaultDocumentProvider::class.java, BuildConfig.DOCUMENTS_AUTHORITY).build()

    // any test goes here

}
```

When I run the test, it throws an exception when initializing the `ProviderTestRule`:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Provider must be exported
at android.provider.DocumentsProvider.attachInfo(DocumentsProvider.java:168)
at androidx.test.rule.provider.ProviderTestRule$Builder.createProvider(ProviderTestRule.java:529)
at androidx.test.rule.provider.ProviderTestRule$Builder.build(ProviderTestRule.java:482)
at com.example.asd.ExampleInstrumentedTest.<init>(ExampleInstrumentedTest.kt:22)
```

I've tried all permutations of `exported`, `permission` etc for the Provider, but to no avail.
Is ProviderTestRule not the way to go here? Am I using it wrong? Or is there a bug somewhere?

Comment: `123` probably is not your authority string, and you need to pass your authority to the `Builder` constructor, based on [the docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/rule/provider/ProviderTestRule.Builder#ProviderTestRule.Builder(java.lang.Class%3CT%3E,%20java.lang.String)).

Comment: My bad, that was  a copy paste mistake. Same behavior with the right authority unfortunately.

Comment: It is possible that the `android:permission` is somehow confusing it. Temporarily remove that and see if your test gets farther. You need that permission, but it might indicate whether this is some limitation/bug in `ProviderTestRule`.

Comment: If I remove ```android:permission``` I have to also remove ```android:grantUriPermissions```, which requires ```exported``` to be removed as well. Then I'm back at ```Provider must be exported``` but this time from ```at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6288)```.

Comment: "If I remove android:permission I have to also remove android:grantUriPermissions" -- for what I was thinking of, I don't believe that is required. After all, `FileProvider` uses `android:grantUriPermissions` without `android:permission`. Again, this change will break your provider, but I was hoping things would survive long enough to see if `ProviderTestRule` cannot work with permission-protected providers or something.

Comment: Otherwise, if you can create a demo project that reproduces the problem, file a bug report. There are a grand total of two `ProviderTestRule` issues, neither of which seem like they are what you are seeing.